Using dried peel in lemon curd
I’m using dried organic Meyer lemon peel in my lemon curd recipe instead of lemon zest. Do I need to reconstitute it before I use it? I’ve never made curd before so any ideas are helpful. Warm Regards

Hi Elizabeth! This is totally a valid question, but I'm curious why you're not using fresh zest here. You need to juice a bunch of lemons for the curd, so why not use the zest of the same lemons? Pro tip: make sure to take the zest off before you juice them!

You'll need to grind or puree the peel, and that's going to be much easier once it's reconstituted. So yes, unless your dried peel is granulated (or you have the equipment to grind it while dry) you should reconstitute it.
